# AviSynth can't open my AVI file: "AVISource: Couldn't locate a decompressor for fourcc dvds"

Tags: codec, virtualdub, avi

I simply want to open an AVI file with AviSynth and feed it into VirtualDub. However, when I open my `.avs` script (consisting of just one `AviSource()` call), I get the following error:

```
Avisynth open failure:
AVISource: Couldn't locate a decompressor for fourcc dvds
(H:\Videos\QTGMC\test.avs, line 1)
```

The required dvsd codec seems to be installed, according to software called GSpot (which identifies a video file's required codec's). Does anyone know why I can't open this file and how to fix it?

Comment: The error message would indicate your codec doesn't have the correct functionality. Maybe it is faulty. You could try reinstalling.

Comment: @DrMayhem I must have come pre-installed, since I never installed it. And I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same issue in the future, I solved it by installing Cedocida codec: http://www.cithraidt.de/cedocida/index.html#download.

Using `DirectShowSource()` instead of `AviSource()` also works.